# sqlalchemy error says no column exist in sqlite table when I can see it in the db browser

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I get the following error when trying to access a view in my routes. Currently there are no upf entries in the database. This is the view I am using to create a page to inject entries into the database, but it says the timestamp is missing. The timestamp column shows up in my database viewer and in my create table statement.

Here is the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: upf.timestamp
[SQL: SELECT f.id AS f_id, f.body AS f_body, f.timestamp AS f_timestamp, f.language AS f_language, f.parent_id AS f_parent_id
FROM f, upfd
WHERE ? = upfd.f_id AND f.id = upfd.f_id ORDER BY upf.timestamp DESC
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: (4, 25, 0)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Here is the route that generates the error:

```
@bp.route('/f/<int:f_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def f(f_id=0):
    if f_id==0:
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    upform=UpForm()
    f=f.query.get(f_id)

    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    up_fs=f.upfs.order_by(Upf.timestamp.desc()).paginate(
            page, current_app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'], False)
    up_next_url = url_for('main.up_fs', page=up_fs.next_num) \
        if up_fs.has_next else None
    up_prev_url = url_for('main.up_fs', page=up_fs.prev_num) \
        if up_fs.has_prev else None
    return render_template('f.html', title=_('f'), upform=upform,
                           upfs=upfs.items, up_next_url=up_next_url,
                           up_prev_url=up_prev_url)
```

Here is the model I am using

```
class Upf(SearchableMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'upf'
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    #Update to wikipedia style with formatting etc
    body = db.Column(db.String(1024))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    language = db.Column(db.String(5))

    #filter duplicates

    #manytomany
    sources = db.relationship('Upf', secondary=upfd, backref='upsources')

    def __repr__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return '<Upf: > %r' % (self.id)
```

Here is the migration that creates the table

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_f_timestamp'), 'f', ['timestamp'], unique=False)
    op.create_table('upf',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('body', sa.String(length=1024), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('timestamp', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('language', sa.String(length=5), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
```

Comment: It should be `upfd.timestamp` and not `upf.timestamp`.

Comment: I tried that and it gave this error :
 NameError: name 'UpFd' is not defined
Not sure where to go from here.